# Add Span to Label ID

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to add a span to a label for which I don't have access to the HTML as it's output from RSForms Pro.  I would like to add a tooltip span to individual labels so when the person rolls their mouse over, they get some information.

Here is what the code looks like:

```
<p class="rsformVerticalClear"><input name="form[Services_DM][]" type="checkbox" value="Death Records Retrieval/Search" id="Services_DM0"><label for="Services_DM0">Death Records Retrieval/Search</label></p>
```

The next option has the class Services_DM1 and so forth.

How do I go about adding a span to "Death Records Retrieval/Search" without having access to the actual code? Is there a way to inject it?

Comment: how about using jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

How are you inserting the code into your page? Anything embedded (such as an Iframe) will be barred from being manipulated from (or, IIRC, accessed by) your javascript due to [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) concerns.

Assuming your html and the loaded html are rendered into the same document, you'd want to use the [HTML DOM](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) functions to manipulate the html post load.  This function should do what you want:

```
function addToolTip(elementid, content, classname) {
    var theelement=document.getElementById(elementid);
    var thetooltip=document.createElement('span');
    var thetext = document.createTextNode(content);
    thetooltip.appendChild(thetext);
    thetooltip.setAttribute('class',classname);
    theelement.appendChild(thetooltip);
}
```

To generate a tooltip, just call addToolTip with your label's element, whatever content text you'd like to see within the tooltip, and a css class (I figured you may want this for styling).

Answer (score 0):

You can target all the labels with class starting from **"Services_DM"** and append a **span** to them:

try this jQuery sample snippet.

```
var $span = $('<span>My span contents here </span>');
$('label[class^="Services_DM"]').each(function(index,item){
   $(this).append($span);
});
```

The above code is not tested, for reference purpose only!